# aspx page which isn't rendering

Tags: asp.net

I Need to make a webpage.  asp.net

this webpage recieve parameter by using Request.Querystring

and Redirect webpage.

in this page, no need to render.

what should I write code in  .aspx  file?

does this aspx file need html tag?

or

only  `<%@ Page %>` need to be coded?

> 

Comment: I'm really sorry about my poor english!

Comment: You don´t need any other tags than the page tag in your aspx, place your code in the codeBehind and have the Page-Load method use Response.Redirect(newUrl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a Asp.net HttpHandler(ashx file). This way there will be no aspx tags and you will get the redirection done in code-behind only

Comment: well. ashx doesn't inherit 'System.Web.UI.Page', so I can't use Response.Redirect()    is there any way to solve?

Comment: Something like HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect


---- lookup the exact yntax